# How can I show formatted html content in text area using js or jquery or php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

For instance consider the following string:

```
<div><span class="author-advanced">hello <b>everyone</b></span></div>
```

It should print:

> hello **everyone**

I'm using HTML5 editor. I've saved this string in mysql db and after retrieving it, I want to append it to text editor while keeping all formatting. What function/approach should be adopted to fix this?

Comment: HTML5 editor might have documentation on how to achieve what you need. If you using DIV as an editor make sure it contentEditable, if you are using a textrea, the designMode needs to be activated.

Comment: I'm able to append the text- hello everyone- to text editor. But my question is about the formatting For instance while appending text here, I want the word 'everyone' to be in strong. How do I maintain this formatting?

Comment: As mentioned earlier, what is the editor? can you show us the  code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `<textarea>` you need to put the `HTML` code inside the tag before initializing the editor. (in this case the `<textarea>` is converted to an `<iframe>`, that's the behavior of WYSIWYG editors using `<textarea>`)

```
<textarea class="editor"><span class="author-advanced">hello <b>everyone</b></span></textarea>
```

If the editor doesn't use a `<textarea>` then it use `contenteditable="true"` attribute to display formatted HTML.

```
<div class="editor" contenteditable="true"><span class="author-advanced">hello <b>everyone</b></span></div>
```

Suppose HTML5Editor() is a function to initialize the editor:

```
 $('.editor').HTML5Editor();
```

The HTML code must be inside the element before initializing the editor.